# How to record the running music Windows 8 metro app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, audio-recording

I am making a music based app. The app has the functionality of playing a music from the music library of the user and the user has a chance to play different type of instruments i.e. Drums parallel to the music being played.

What I want to do is, start a recording session and record both the sounds being getting out of the music app i.e. The background song together with the drum sounds that the user is making.

How do I do that in C#/xaml?

I have googled about it and didn't find anything useful :(

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far? At what point are you. Is playing the background-song while overlaying it with the drums played by user interaction already implemented?

Comment: Yes it is. I am waiting how to write code, when the user will click on the 'record' button.

Comment: Have you read this article? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67568/Creating-a-Sound-Recorder-in-C-and-C  it gives you a good start how to proceed.